# regex end with close bracket not worked

Tags: regex

I have string  :

```
Lorem ipsum....
aws_oracle_ext.get_package_variable('THIS','IS','A');
Lorem ipsum....
aws_oracle_ext.get_package_variable
('THIS','IS','B')    Lorem ipsum....  aws_oracle_ext.get_package_variable('THIS'
   ,'IS','C')    Lorem ipsum....  aws_oracle_ext.get_package_variable
    ('THIS'
     ,'IS',
     'D');
Lorem ipsum....
```

I want to grep values :

```
aws_oracle_ext.get_package_variable('THIS','IS','A')
aws_oracle_ext.get_package_variable('THIS','IS','B')
aws_oracle_ext.get_package_variable('THIS','IS','C')
aws_oracle_ext.get_package_variable('THIS','IS','D')
```

I tried with regex :

```
 ^aws_oracle_ext.get_package_variable.*\)$
```

but it's not worked.
Could you tell me what wrong?

Comment: In what way did it not work? We also need actual output to help you with it.

Comment: `^aws_oracle_ext.get_package_variable[^)]*\)`

Comment: @R.Schifini Thank you, with your expression, I just remove ^ and it's worked as expected

Answer (score 0):

I see the following problems with your regular expression.

1. It has the `^` and the `$` anchors, which prevents the expression from matching substrings.
2. There is no semicolon in the regex, but there are in the input, consider appending `;?` to your regex.
3. You need some flags to enable your regex to match multi-line strings, which depends on the language environment you use. (e.g. JavaScript, PHP, Perl, POSIX)
4. Also noted in the comments, you need to exclude `)` from the part of regex matching the arguments. You should change `.*` to `[^)]*`.

Lastly, regex on itself doesn't change the matched string. You need to first match the substring you want to extract, then perform substitution to remove unwanted characters (such as `<newline>` and `<space>`).